# How to add multiple views to one template in django?

Tags: django

How to add multiple views in one template of django ?

Is it possible to add more than one view in template . 
I have view A that deals with file uploads , and view B that deals with file permissions . How do I put them in one template ? Both are in different apps .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is really the best way to go about things. Views are not really meant to be used that way. They should map to requests on a one to one basis.

You might, in fact, need to write a third view which does all the things that the two other views do. Situations like this are where the class based views become very handy. I would try to break out the code that handles all the forms and processing in to separate functions, and just import those when needed.

Another Solution is to do this via ajax somehow. Load those portions of the page separately either after load, or on submit.

Answer (score -2):

You should use custom middleware for that kind of things, so there's no need for different views.

Comment: Custom middleware like ? A little bit more of an explanation would really help

Comment: Read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/?from=olddocs. You can write middleware to automatically upload files to the server, or restrict some pages.

Comment: I don't think middleware is a great idea. One reason being that it will get called for every request, not just the relevant ones. You'd need to do a whole bunch of checks that duplicate what the django url routing does already. Another reason being it's not really where processing of objects typically goes. Convention really says to put this in a view.